# rbenv not showing the available ruby versions

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have installed `rbenv` in my vagrant machine but when I try to list all the available ruby versions `rbenv versions` then it gives me this output:

`system (set by /home/vagrant/.rbenv/version)`

Does anyone know what is this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Are you asking what the output of that command means? I'm looking at the [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-version), and I think it indicates that rbenv only knows of one version of ruby - the version that came installed with your system.

Edit: If that's not the answer you were looking for, can you tell us what you expected to see? Did you have other versions installed on that machine?

Edit 2: If you want to see a list of versions you can install onto your machine, but aren't installed yet, run:

```
rbenv install --list
```

Here is [more documentation for this command](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build). This will help!

Comment: Hmm, I want to look at all the available ruby versions from which I can chose the desired one to install. I don't remember but last time I ran some command which gave me a list of all the ruby versions and from that I chose `1.9.3-p0`

Comment: Okay, I think are looking for a different command, then. Rbenv is listing all of the ruby versions that are currently on your machine. See my edit.

Comment: It would be much simpler for rbenv to have an `rbenv list` command

Comment: Currently only `rbenv install --list-all` will show all versions available for installation

Answer (score 53):

If you have tried both `rbenv install --list` and `ruby-build --definitions` and still can't see the latest Ruby versions on the list, then you need to upgrade `ruby-build` because that is what `rbenv` uses to "know" the available versions.

For example, assuming you use Mac OS X and installed `ruby-build` using Homebrew, you can update `ruby-build` by invoking:

```
brew upgrade ruby-build
```

Now, try listing the available versions again, and you should see the latest ones there.

Edit:

The `ruby-build` [wiki](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki#wiki-updating-ruby-build) lists a couple of ways of updating it, namely the above one using Homebrew and another one where it is installed as a plugin to `rbenv`:

```
cd "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build && git pull
```

Answer (score 20):

Rbenv is usually installed with it's companion `ruby-build`

You can get the versions available to be installed with:

```
ruby-build --definitions
```

Answer (score 19):

To get a list of available ruby versions you can install, type the following:

`rbenv install -l`

To get a list of the ruby versions already installed on your machine, type the following:

`rbenv versions`

---

To answer your question as to what the below means:

`system (set by /home/vagrant/.rbenv/version)`

This is telling you that the system ruby (the default ruby installed on your system) is the only ruby version installed on your vagrant machine. Rbenv is using the default system ruby because it doesn't have any other ruby versions installed yet.

Answer (score 7):

To see all available versions:

```
rbenv install --list-all
```

Or

```
rbenv install --list
```

To list only stable releases for each Ruby implementation.

Comment: Only `rbenv install --list-all` will list available versions to install

Comment: ``rbenv install --list`` is for stable releases only, it's stated at the end of the command output:

```Only latest stable releases for each Ruby implementation are shown.
Use 'rbenv install --list-all / -L' to show all local versions.```

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu has an outdated list of Ruby versions (due to an outdated version of `ruby-build` which is installed in `/usr/bin/ruby-build`).

After an installation of `rbenv` (by `apt install rbenv`), it is required to add an up-to-date version of `ruby-build` by running

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
```

When this is already done, the definitions can easily be updated by calling

```
git -C "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build pull
```

as is mentioned in another answers as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac
`brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build` also works. 
[Documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#upgrading-with-homebrew)

Answer (score 3):

#### List `rbenv` versions that are possible to install

"Only latest stable releases for each Ruby implementation are shown.

With the fewest key strokes (shorter than --list and --list-all)

```sh
rbenv install -l
```

#### Want to see what is available from rbenv to install?

```sh
ruby-build --definitions
```

#### Want to narrow that down a bit?

```sh
ruby-build --definitions | grep 3.0
```

To upgrade to the latest rbenv and update ruby-build with newly released Ruby versions, upgrade the Homebrew packages:

```sh
brew update && brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
```

Also you can always just type `rbenv`
Which will give you a help menu

```sh
rbenv
```

TLDR the manpage or github repo or just plain forgot?

Take a peek at this site for quick `rbenv` recollection:

https://devhints.io/rbenv

[Also, you may need to `brew upgrade` if you have installed with brew see here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build).

Comment: But this is useless without an updated `ruby-build`.

Comment: Indeed. But it is not self _updating_. Thus merely calling `rbenv install -l` does not solve the original problem of finding out what ruby versions are available _now_. See my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129103/where-is-ruby-3-0-0-on-rbenv The point in general, though, is that this answer doesn't contribute anything that isn't already present in other answers.