# where is ruby 3.0.0 on rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

`rbenv install --list-all` shows me, among many other things of course,

```
3.0.0-dev
3.0.0-preview1
3.0.0-preview2
```

But where is `3.0.0` itself, the actual final release? I'd like to try it out. Not all announced features made it into the previews so I need the real thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`rbenv install` passes thru `ruby-build`. You need to update (`brew upgrade` if installed via Homebrew) your `ruby-build` in order to see the latest versions.

Answer (score 8):

### Ubuntu

(I prefer cloning the repo to get the latest version of rbenv). If you are ok with outdated verions, then use a package manager: `sudo apt install rbenv`

**Install using git**:

1. `git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv` **   (pulls latest ruby versions)
2. `rbenv install 3.0.0` (or for later versions: 3.x.x)
3. `echo "3.0.0" > .ruby-version` OR `rbenv local 3.0.0` to ensure ruby 3.0.0 is used. Of course, choose your ruby version: `3.x.x`.

### Mac

```
brew upgrade
```

### Obsolete instructions:

** Older versions had the following: `git -C ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull`

Comment: (i improved the formatting) - but substantive credit to @RichSteinmetz

Comment: And to me. All in all seems rather otiose to me, just repeating both existing answers.

Comment: @matt yes absolutely agreed --> the only difference is in formatting. but my theory is that formatting does makes a big difference. this will be an interesting academic experiment nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for the upvote! I think step 3 is very specific and not always needed for the upgrade itself. Also I think, `rbenv local 3.0.0` would do the same?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04/rbenv 1.02, there's no `plugins` directory, only `shims` and `versions`.

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike thx - i have updated instructions

Answer (score 7):

#### On Ubuntu

Short answer:

```sh
# You need to update the available versions via ruby-build
~ git -C ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull
~ rbenv install 3.0.0
...
Installed ruby-3.0.0 to ~/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0
```

Long answer with a beautiful picture: https://richstone.io/where-is-ruby-3-0-0-on-rbenv/

Comment: I don't know for which Ubuntu version that is, but I don't have a directory like `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build` on 22.04.